# Catching Custom Exception with JUnit

Tags: java, junit

I am writing a `JUnit` test case for a method in which I am trying to catch an `exception` but for some reason my test is not hitting the exception. Method is long but I just need to catch exception which is in the `if` block.

Method under test:

```
public void createClient() throws EISClientException {
    if( client == null ) {
        ClientConfig c = new ClientConfig();

        //Add Glocal JSON/Jackson Provider
        c.register( JacksonFeature.class );

        if ( isDisableSslValidation() ) {  
            try {
                client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().sslContext( SslUtil.createGullibleSslContext() )
                            .hostnameVerifier( SslUtil.gullibleVerifier ).withConfig( c ).build();
            } catch( Exception e ) {
                throw new EISClientException( e );
            }
        } else {
            client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().withConfig( c ).build();
        }

        //Add Client Properties
        if( clientProperties.size() > 0 ) {
            for( String key : clientProperties.keySet() ) {
                client.property( key, clientProperties.get( key ) );
            }
        }

        //Add Client Filters
        if( clientFilters != null && clientFilters.size() > 0 ) {
            for( IClientFilter cf : clientFilters ) {
                client.register( cf.getFilter() );
            }
        }

    }
}
```

JUnit test:

```
@Test
public void testCreateClientException() throws Exception {
    ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = new ClientConfiguration();
    Client client = mock(Client.class);

    boolean caughtException = false;
    try {
        clientConfiguration.setDisableSslValidation(true);
        client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().build();
        clientConfiguration.createClient();

    } catch (EISClientException ex) {
        caughtException = true;
    }
    assertTrue(caughtException);
}
```

Looks like if the client is not built then throw `exception` but if I pass `null` as an argument in any of the methods surely I get `NullPointerException`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that the creation of client is really throwing a custom exception?

Comment: I said that, "Looks like". This means not sure just guessing.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting up a mock client before you execute your test. In the method that you are testing, it starts `if (client == null)` I think this is evaluating to false and nothing is being processed in the method

Comment: But he is not passing the mocked client anywhere right. ? Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @DJ You are right. I'm thinking that it must be setting up a Singleton or a static instance. But I'm not sure

Answer (score 0):

Actually, in JUnit there is a more concise way of verifying an exception was thrown:

```
@Test(expected=EISClientException.class)
public void testCreateClientException() throws Exception {
    ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = new ClientConfiguration();
    Client client = mock(Client.class);
    clientConfiguration.setDisableSslValidation(true);
    client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().build();
    clientConfiguration.createClient();
}
```

This test will only succeed if the exception is thrown (I'm aware this doesn't directly answer your question)

Comment: I am aware of this and I've tried it this way but no luck.